# Shift / reduce conflicts in grammar of arithmetic expression with n-ary sums / products

Tags: parsing, grammar, shift-reduce-conflict

Parsing binary sums / products are easy, but I'm having troubles defining a grammar that parses

```
a + b * c + d + e
```

as

```
sum(a, prod(b, c), d, e)
```

My initial (naive) attempt generated 61 shift / reduce conflicts.

I'm using java cup (but I suppose a solution for any other parser generator would be easily translated).

Comment: Can we see the code for your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following ANTLR grammar:

```
parse
  :  exp EOF
  ;

exp
  :  add_exp
  ;

add_exp
  :  mul_exp ('+' mul_exp)* 
  ;

mul_exp
  :  atom ('*' atom)* 
  ;

atom
  :  Number
  |  '(' exp ')'
  ;

Number
  :  'a'..'z'
  ;
```

parses the input `a + b * c + d + e` as:

[alt text http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7099/17212574.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/7099/17212574.png)

As you can see, the `mul_exp` is the furthest away in the tree and (using an appropriate "walk" through your tree) will be evaluated first.

and the input `a + b * (c + d) + e` is parsed as:

[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/2207/89332200.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/2207/89332200.png)

The images were generated with [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html).

**EDIT:**

A tool like [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html) makes debugging a grammar a breeze! For example, if I click on the `atom` rule in the grammar above, the following is automatically generated and displayed at the bottom of the screen:

[alt text http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/6793/53395907.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/6793/53395907.png)

Of course, that rule isn't complex at all, but when you do get to work with more complex rules, it's pretty darn easy to visualize them like that.

HTH.

Comment: Beautiful answer. I can see right away why this works. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know about ANTLRWorks.. thanks for the link as well.